# Expectation of number of points in an infinite uniform grid covered by convex polygon of area A

Tags: probability, geometry, area

Given an infinite uniform grid of points on in a 2d space, is the expectation of the number of grid points covered by a randomly placed convex polygon its area A? Would it be the same if the polygon could be concave?

Fixed: the polygon is put in a n*n torus where n is larger than the diameter of the polygon (length of longest distance of two vertices on the polygon).

Comment: I think so. Should be true for any reasonable set (not just a polygon). This isn't an answer; I look forward to seeing one. Since it's hard to place a structure at random on the plane you might have to phrase this as placing it at random on a large enough torus. That would require a bounded set.

Comment: This question needs a bit more structure. Specifically regarding the "random placement" of the polygon. Keep in mind that there is no uniform distribution on an infinite plane. I think Ethan made a good suggestion by potentially defining a sufficiently large bounded support. Then, the centroid of the polygon could be randomly placed without much likelihood of it having any region outside the support.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have modified the question so that the polygon can be placed at random on a torus and doesn't intersect itself.

Comment: Also, I think maybe the polygon could be interchanged with any set, the problem should be similar to the process of naive Monte Carlo integration

Comment: Can the polygon be rotated? (I think the answer is the same, but the proof might be different.)

Comment: The polygon can be rotated.

Comment: What do yo call an "infinite uniform grid". Of type $\mathbb{Z+iZ}$ ? or more general $\mathbb{Z}+\omega \mathbb{Z}$  for any complex number $\omega$ ?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed just Monte Carlo integration in disguise. Fix the (reasonably regular) figure on the torus. Now repeatedly place the (origin of the) grid at random. The $n^2$ points will be uniformly distributed on the torus and will be in the figure in proportion to its area.